# Animating Background Image

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make the background image move back and forwards between 0% and 100% with no luck.

```
#swipe {
   position:absolute;
   background-image:url(images/title-back-grade.png);
   background-position:50% 0%;
   height: 250px;
   width: 100%;
   top: 108px;
   left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

<div id="swipe"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#swipe').css({backgroundPosition:"(50% 0)"});
$('#swipe').animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(-1% 0)"}, 
        {duration:500});

});
```

Can some one help me?

Comment: Try using actual pixel values. I don't think animating values in percentages is supported. Although I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

When you say percent, it becomes ambigous as percentage of what? A better way would be to calculate the pixels values (if you do not want to use hard coded values) and use those.

Take a look at this tuturial (if yo haven't already) for some nice examples on animating background using pixel values: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

Comment: pixel values would be a problem as 0% and 100% align nicely to the browser window regardless to its size. I'm not sure I could calculate percentage to pixels at least not with my knolledge.

Comment: Well, if you mean 100% of visible portion of broswer window, then its ` $(window).width()` will give you 100% of "visible" width. To get 50%, multiply the value with 0.5. `0% -> 0px` :)

Answer (score 0):

This can get you started

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/nTWFt/

```
function animateBg() {
  var bg = $('#swipe');
  bg.animate({left: '-=5000px' }, 10000, 
   function()  {  
     bg.animate({left: '+=5000px' }, 10000,
       function() {                
         animateBg();
       });
   });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   animateBg();  
});
```

Comment: Not ideal but it works ... $(document).ready(function() {
 $pos = 50;
 $dir = 1;
 window.setInterval(movement, 10);
});

function movement() {
 
 $('#swipe').css({backgroundPosition: $pos+"% 0px"});
 
 if ($pos==100)
 {
  $dir = -1;
 }
 if ($pos==0)
 {
  $dir = 1;
 }
 $pos = $pos + $dir;
} Just not in IE

Comment: @Stephen Brown yes that another solution why not posting it as an answer? you can post your answer and set it as anwsered too.