# How can I animate the background image after remove a class using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to animate the background image of a div on the removal of a class. The closest answer I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058812/animating-background-image).

The code is like:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="bkg-switch" style="background-image:url(image-1.jpg)"></div>

// JavaScript - On page load
jQuery( '.bkg-switch' ).css( 'background-image', 'url(image-2.jpg)' );
jQuery( '.bkg-switch' ).removeClass( '.bkg-switch' );
```

Basically, I need an animation effect here instead of a flickering switch.

Comment: By animation, do you mean fade?

Comment: Anything which is decent enough to swap the image instead of having a flicker effect.